# Connecting to Cassandra from remote machine

Tags: c#, ubuntu, cassandra, nosql

I want to ask for your help on how can connect to my Cassandra DB on my droplet from remote machine. I did everything that is written in this article: [Install Cassandra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqrGz.png) but when I try to connect from my C# code:

```
cluster = Cassandra.Cluster.Builder()
    .WithCredentials("abc", "abc")
    .AddContactPoints(new[] { "12.34.56.78" })
    .WithPort(9168)
    .Build();

var session = cluster.Connect();
var keyspace = "Test";
session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists(keyspace);
session.ChangeKeyspace(keyspace);
```

I'm getting an Exception:

> 'Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException' in Cassandra.dll
>
> Additional information: None of the hosts tried for query are available
> (tried: 12.34.56.78:9168)

I also tried from other Cassandra GUI Clients like DBeaver but I'm getting the same error.

My Droplet is Ubuntu 14.04. From localhost I have no problem with Cassandra my only problem is from remote.

Here is result from

> sudo netstat -plunt

[image: Open Ports]

Why could this be and how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you also the cassandra.yaml? Only the parts with an IP. Seeds etc.

Comment: Yes, I set listen_adress to be server's IP address where Cassandra is installed and also I changed seed to servers IP too. In authenticator I changed to PasswordAllowed to protect my Cassandra.                        # ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
listen_address: 46.101.183.187
# listen_interface: eth0
# listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false                                                         - seeds: "46.101.183.187"                                                        authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator

Comment: Is there a reason to use `9168`, instead of default `9042`?

Comment: As I know 9042 is for thrift, and 9168 is for other type of connections. But I tried with both ports and still getting the same error.

Comment: You're connecting to 12.34.56.78 but i think this isn't the real ip, or? You use 46.101.183.187 in your application?

Comment: Yes right, i just put it as an example my real IP is 46.101.183.187 and I've set everything according to it.

Comment: Please check your open ports: sudo netstat -plunt   and post it in your main post :) Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an internal IP? Use this instead of the public IP.

Comment: I put a print screen after the netstat command. But isn't it only for internal use? How my remote machine will find it connect, i will need a VPN connection?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use port 9042.

listen_interface is used to setup inter-node communication.

> The IP address or hostname that Cassandra binds to for connecting to other Cassandra nodes. Set this parameter or listen_interface, not both.

You have to change rpc_address and then restart cassandra daemon

> (Default: localhost) The listen address for client connections (Thrift RPC service and native transport). Valid values are:

Answer (score 0):

> make sure you can run cqlsh locally, i.e. from the host where Cassandra is running. If you can not, check if Cassandra is running (check logs) and listens on the interface you are connecting to.
>
> if you can connect locally, check you settings for rpc_address and rpc_broadcast_address for Cassandra. It should be set to other value than 'localhost' (which is set by default).
>
> 9042 port is for CQL by default, I suggest you not to reset it.

Comment: Yes, i already wrote in my question that I have no problem for local access main problem is that I can't connect via my code. I'm using this droplet as database server, I have nothing else installed on it except Cassandra.

Comment: so, have you checked rpc_address and rpc_broadcast_address settings?